# Save json into mongo with preselected ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I receive JSON string from a web service.

```
{
    clientid: 123456,
    text: abc
}
```

I need to save this json into mongodb and use **clientid** as the **_id** field. How do I indicate that to nodejs? I'm using [MONK](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really all you need to do in manipulate the object you get after parsing the JSON string:

```js
  var db = require('monk')('localhost/test')
, collection = db.get('example');

  var json = '{ "clientid": 123456, "text": "abc" }';
  var obj = JSON.parse( obj );

  obj._id = obj.clientid;
  delete obj.clientid;

  collection.insert( obj, function(err,doc) {
     // work in here
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, Neil. Is there anyway to keep the field name?

Comment: @Guoming Sure. Just don't delete the key. You can basically manipulaate the object how you want. The only thing here is making sure there is a value in `_id` otherwise the default `ObjectId` will be assigned.